# Can I live-preview the results of a pull request before accepting it?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My boss has an idea for our website and I'm wondering how possible this is.

We want to bring on non-technical people into the approval process for pull-requests on Github. For example, we have someone who's job is assure the accuracy of the things we are saying, and we have someone else who's job is to make sure the website has a good design.

The problem is that neither of these people are technical and can't read code nor use a software like Git Bash. We would like them to somehow be able to preview the changes of a pull request to see how it looks (rather than seeing the code itself). Is something like this possible with Git? If not then how else can we integrate them into the

Comment: This is a bit too broad for stackoverflow though you could use something like travis-ci to deploy the pull request branch to some sort of "staging" environment and then provide a link via a github integration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  It is called, "have a proper release channel"

Once you do that, you can build your release from a Git branch and install it.

As long as you are "deploying via git checkout" you'll never get what you want.  The problem is that the order of operations work against you.

With a proper release channel, the order of operations look like

- Commit the code
- Build the installable
- Install the installable

But since Building the installable is its own step, you can reorder the steps:

- Build the installable (pre commit)
- Install the installable (pre commit)
- Commit the code
- Build the installable (post commit)
- Install the installable (post commit)

With a short-cut avoiding explicit construction of an installable, you are limiting your ability to install to your ability to commit.  As a result your work flow looks like

- Commit the code
- Install the commit

It is the lack of an installable that is hindering you at this moment.  With it you will be able to build the installable for any branch, and then deploy experimental changes to servers for verification before you go live.

For a website, I wouldn't get too fancy.  A Zip file like installable will probably be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools that accomplish the task of automating Pull Request previews, for example [Tugboat](https://tugboat.qa).